# How to use django REST view from regular view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got this api view

```
class ItemList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Item

    def get_queryset(self):
      return get_objects_for_user('item_view',self.request.user)
```

and another app view (not part of the API)

```
def item_search(request):
    qs = get_objects_for_user('item_view',request.user)

    q = request.GET.get('q',None)
    qs.filter ( ... )
    paginator = Paginator(qs['queryset'], 20)
    ..
```

**What is the best way to use the `get_queryset` from the API view in the regular view ?**

I have some permission \ filtering going on and i want to keep the views as DRY as possible.

I've poked around the code and saw that generic views are instantiated with `ItemList.initizlie(request)` but i keep stumbling walls there which leads me to think that this may not be the solution ...

**EDIT :**

Closest i got so far was `ItemList.as_view()(request)` - it returns the data but it's still not enough, i need th QS so i can apply additional filtering on it.

Answer (score 0):

The Django-Rest-Framework views are based on the Django class-based views. In addition to this, the method-names picked are the same as in the Django generic views.

I would say the best way is to build a mixin that is used both in the API-view and the "normal" view. This mixin could provide `get_queryset` (and others). If you keep the names standard, both *real* views will be quite small and most logic will be in your mixin.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your answer. I'm not looking for a way to mixin the API get_queryset into the regular view - i'm looking for a way to consume the resource from the API given a request to a regular view (The API job is to extract / serialize / screen the data, the regular's view job is to render an html response - They serve different purposes and should remain separate).

Comment: Your question was "What is the best way to use the get_queryset from the API view in the regular view ?" ;) 

I understand your idea (use the DRF View in your Django view), but I still think the cleanest approach to this here is to put the shared behavior into a seperate class which is used by the Rest-Framework view and the Django view.